# Program debugging using Valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

I am trying to solve a problem of "Multiplying a number by 11".Number can be any long.I am getting SIGABRT error.

I tried to debug using valgrind, but i don't know to solve it(saw many questions of valgrind on stackoverflow but no success).I am stuck on this problem since last week.

Code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CHUNK 10

void get_input(char *val,int *i){
    char ch,*tmp=NULL;
    int size;
    size=CHUNK;
    while(ch=getc(stdin),ch!=EOF && ch!='\n'){
        val[(*i)++]=ch;
        if(*i>=size){
            size+=CHUNK;
            tmp=realloc(val,size);
            if(!tmp){
                free(val);
                val=NULL;
                break;
            }
            val=tmp;
        }
    }
    val[*i]='\0';
}

void mul_11(char *val,int *i){
    int *digit,iter,j,carry=0,num,temp;
    iter=*i;
    digit=(int*)malloc((iter+2)*sizeof(int));
    for(j=iter-1;j>=0;j--){
        temp=val[j]-'0';
        num=temp*11+carry;
        digit[j+2]=num%10;
        carry=num/10;
    }
    digit[1]=carry%10;
    digit[0]=carry/10;
    if(digit[0]==0)
        temp=1;
    else
        temp=0;

    for(j=temp;j<=iter+1;j++)
        printf("%d",digit[j]);
    free(digit);
    digit=NULL;
    *i=0;
}
int main() {
    int t,i=0;
    char *val=NULL;
    scanf("%d ",&t);
    while(t--){
        val=(char*)malloc(CHUNK*sizeof(char));
            get_input(val,&i);
            mul_11(val,&i);
            printf("\n");
        free(val);
        val=NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Whole code with input can be found out [**Geeksforgeeks code here**](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/44SOuQvxud)

Valgrind error :

```
5555555555555555555555555555555555555
==2349== Invalid read of size 1
==2349==    at 0x4008CE: mul_11 (mul11.c:30)
==2349==    by 0x400A8A: main (mul11.c:55)
==2349==  Address 0x52044a4 is 20 bytes after a block of size 16 in arena "client"
==2349== 
6111111105-3-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-6-60-8
==2349== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==2349==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2349==    by 0x400AA0: main (mul11.c:57)
==2349==  Address 0x5204480 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 10 free'd
==2349==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2349==    by 0x400809: get_input (mul11.c:13)
==2349==    by 0x400A77: main (mul11.c:54)
==2349==  Block was alloc'd at
==2349==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2349==    by 0x400A60: main (mul11.c:53)
==2349==
```

Comment: And you didn't put all the code because ... ? Ligne number are not very useful here.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Valgrind doesn't even report a problem in the function you show.

Comment: because it would be a long post then

Comment: You could upload your code to a site like pastebin and link to it in your question.

Comment: How are we meant to debug this function when you didn't show what you pass to it to make it fail??

Comment: I have already uploaded it on geeksforgeeks and link is attached

Comment: I am currently new to this platform & learning things.I didn't got anyway to formulate a minimal code that would highlight same problem.
So I posted small function and attached the whole code with geeksforgeeks

Comment: @yogi You should start learning about what a function returns and more over which kind of arguments are expected. I recomand you to turn your GCC Flags ON. Try this `gcc-7 -Wpedantic -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror  -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmisleading-indentation -Wduplicated-cond -Wold-style-definition -Wconversion -Wshadow -Winit-self -Wfloat-equal -Wwrite-strings -O0 -g` . **Check =>>** [This for more about what GCC reports on your Code](https://pastebin.com/raw/hjBxMYQE)

Comment: Any way you should probably use instead of `while ( t-- )` =>> `while ( t > 0 )` and add `t--` at the bottom of your while loop. Then think again about what you need. By making those changes I got [This results](https://pastebin.com/raw/wD4wbmrx)

Comment: You say `scanf("%d ",&t);` and here `t` is an `int` and then your Input is `5555555555555555555555555555555555555` . Are you sure you know what are you do there?

Comment: I don't know where is your exact error, cause your code is unreadable, I just end to remove everything that wasn't necessary and here an working exemple, http://rextester.com/ZKJ52403

Comment: @Stargateur What happens if the OP can not use `getline` ? Probably here will be `#define _GNU_SOURCE` needed. Your code is an infinite loop. Probably a break somewhere should be used too.

Comment: @Michi That just for not have to debug `get_input()` ;), as OP state that the problem come from `mul_11()`... , (and that why I don't post it as answer... I don't think this question will be useful for anyone except the OP). Any other function similar to `getline()` will do the job. "Your code is an infinite loop" ? gné ? "Probably here will be #define _GNU_SOURCE needed.", compile with `std=gnu99` is enough

Comment: @Stargateur I am sure but functions like `getline()` or maybe `strdup()` are not so easy for new commers :). By the Way, good job with `strcspn`

Comment: @Michi There is 4 above that string of 5's, which is input to **scanf("%d ",&t);**
The Code works fine for small input.It gives problem with bigger strings.

Answer (score 0):

If `get_input` reallocs your `val` and it gets a new address, the caller (`main`) will not be told that its value for `val` has become invalid (`realloc` has freed it). `mul_11` will be using freed memory, and `main` will then free it for the second time.

One solution is to send in a pointer to the address, if the function can realloc it, so the caller gets the new values.

```
void get_input(char **valp,int *i){
 char *val = *valp;
...
 val = realloc ...
 *valp = val;
...
```